# change timestamp format pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcFOI.png)How to change the timestamp format which has the format of '2019-12-16-12-40-53' and I want it to convert to '2019-12-16 12:40:53'

I tried

```
    df['timeStamp'] = df['timeStamp'].apply(lambda x: 
                                dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%Y%b%d:%H:%M:%S'))
```

and I got the error

```
    ValueError: time data '2019-12-16-12-40-53' does not match format '%Y%b%d:%H:%M:%S'
```

I am attaching an image of data that I am using as timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and change format with `%m` for match months in numbers with `-` between parts of datetimes:

```
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!